# Substitution trace python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to do a substitution trace for this code:

```
def hanoi(n):
   if n == 1:
       return 1
   else:
       return 2 * hanoi(n - 1) + 1

print hanoi(4)
```

Output:

```
15
```

This is what I did:

```
2 * (4 - 1) + 1

2 * (3) + 1

6 + 1

7
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a **recursion** function and after each step it converted to sub functions with `n-1` :
Actually you have this :

```
2 * hanoi(4 - 1) + 1
2 * hanoi(3) + 1
2 * (2 * hanoi(2) + 1) + 1
2 * (2 * (2 * hanoi(1) + 1) + 1)  + 1
2 * (2 * (2 * 1 + 1) + 1) + 1 = 15
```

Comment: I understand now. I completely forgot to account for the recursion. Thank you for explaining it and showing how its was done.

Answer (score 0):

`2 * hanoi(4-1) + 1` is not the same as `2 * (4-1) + 1`